# Vector Algebra, Addition of vectors

Tags: geometry

Is it possible that 3 vectors, $\overrightarrow{a} +  \overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c} =0$ but $|\overrightarrow{a}|$, $|\overrightarrow{b}|$ and $|\overrightarrow{c}|$ do not represent the sides of a triangle, If yes why? and if no why?. I'm trying to get the solution since last 2 days, so kindly help me out...

Answer (score 5):

For vectors $\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}+\overrightarrow{c}=0$ means exactly that they form a triangle: start to concatenate the vectors at the ending/starting points.

Comment: ...although if the vectors are parallel, then the triangle is degenerate.

Comment: well, yes, maybe that's not considered as "representing the sides of a triangle"

Comment: Depends on who you ask, I guess! :-)

Comment: can't it be 2 vectors parellel in same direction and 3rd vector having magnitude equal to sum of those 2 and is anti-parellel..?

Comment: No. If 2 vectors, say $a$ and $b$ are parallel, then $c=-a-b$ is also parallel to them.